# Attach existing EBS as root device in spot instance request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

Is it possible to include an existing, unattached, available EBS volume as the root device in a spot instance request? I'd like to create a setup where the system is up and running when the spot price is met, and after a termination and the spot price comes back into range I can re-request and start an instance right where I left off.

thanks!

Comment: Not sure if you were able to get the answer for this, if not let us know. As far as I know you should be able to do it if the EBS is on the same zone as of the instance.

Comment: @RakeshS - I'm not aware of such an option, see [my respective answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16328817/45773) for details; so please let us know, if you have a solution or workaround to address Mark's request.

Answer (score 3):

While [Overriding the AMI's Block Device Mapping](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/2011-07-15/UserGuide/index.html?block-device-mapping-concepts.html) as such is possible, the root device is the exception, unfortunately:

> Any instance you launch automatically includes any storage devices in
>   the AMI's block device mapping. You can override that mapping by
>   specifying a block device mapping with the changes that you want at
>   launch time. In your overrides, **you can modify the mapping for any of
>   the storage devices except the root device volume**. *[emphasis mine]*

This is also reflected in the respective wizards within the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/), which only allow to adjust the root volume size, but not the snapshot it is based upon, see the image within 
[Changing the Root Device Volume to Persist](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/RootDeviceStorage.html#Using_RootDeviceStorage).

Comment: Has the situation changed since then? We still cannot reassign root device for existing AMI?

Answer (score 0):

You can boot with the default spot volume, then `pivot_root` init to a separate EBS volume.

The [EC2 Spotter](https://github.com/atramos/ec2-spotter) tool can manage this for you. A snippet from EC2 Spotter's documentation:

> The launch script employs user-data to create a boot-time script that
>   attaches the specified EBS volume to /dev/xvdf and then proceeds to do
>   a pivot_root and chroot in order to use it as the main system disk in
>   place of /dev/xvda. When the instance is first created or restarted
>   following an interruption, the /sbin/init on the AMI-based EBS volume
>   (/dev/xvda1) is replaced with a small shell script which performs the
>   magic pivot_root and chroot and then chain-loads the /sbin/init from
>   the specified persistent EBS volume (/dev/xvdf1). An extra reboot is
>   performed when the instance first comes up, to ensure a clean slate.
>   The end-result is a full Linux system running on the persistent volume
>   dev/xvdf mounted as /. The ephemeral disk remains mounted under
>   /old-root and can be unmounted if needed.

Also see this StackOverflow answer: [AWS EC2: How to remount previous EBS volume using pivot_root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108767/aws-ec2-how-to-remount-previous-ebs-volume-using-pivot-root)